# Why `which pushd` doesn't return anything?

Tags: linux

My understanding is that all commands in linux must exist on the `$PATH`, even for the most basic commands

```
> which cd
/bin/cd
> which ls
/bin/ls
```

But when I tried `which pushd`, to my surprise, it returned:

```
/usr/bin/which: no pushd in (/bin:/usr/share/maven/bin:/usr/share/java/jdk1.8.0_131/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/usr/local/sbin)
```

`pushd` is "installed" and working. This challenges my whole understanding of linux commands.

Can someone explain why this is happening?

Comment: what's output of `pushed`?

Comment: You mean `pushd` without argument? It outputs `-bash: pushd: no other directory`

Comment: Because `pushd` is a shell builtin (it has to be, otherwise how could it manipulate the shell's state such as current directory?)

Comment: @CherryDT what are other examples of such shell builtins?

Comment: I'm rather suprised that you get output from `which cd`, it has exactly the same issue.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not about programming. Maybe try https://unix.stackexchange.com/

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-CD-external-command - `cd` should exist as external command too, where it can't change your directory obviously but it can be used for other purposes like checking whether it is even possible to change to a certain directory (but nowadays it exists only on some distributions). Yet, when you use `cd` in the shell you are still running the builtin and not `/bin/cd`.

Comment: Ok, thank you, now I know what key words to look for.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to unix.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Can someone explain why this is happening?

`pushd`, like many other commands, is a builtin. `which` is itself an executable and `which` searches for executables - there is no such executable as `pushd`.

To affect the current working directory of the shell itself, it has to be a builtin, just like `cd`.

You can check what it is with `type`:

```
$ type pushd
pushd is a shell builtin
```

> what are other examples of such shell builtins?

They are listed in documentation: https://www.gnu.org/savannah-checkouts/gnu/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Builtin-Commands .

Comment: What may cause confusion is that part of the builtins "should" exist as executables as well (even if they can't always be used to their full extent this way), but not every Linux distribution does that or does it for the same builtins. https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/50058/what-is-the-point-of-the-CD-external-command